# react-native-camera---undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.propTypes.oneOfType)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I want to open barcode scanner project on my device but I have a problem with this. I think, I import react-native-camera wrong way in my project. Can you help me about this problem?

[image]

- npm: `6.4.1`
- react-native-cli: `2.0.1`
- react-native: `0.57.1`

**

> My package.json file :

**

```
{
  "name": "BarcodeScanner",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**

> My App.js file :

```
import React, {Component,PropTypes} from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import {RNCamera} from "react-native-camera";

class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      qrcode: ""
    };
  }

  onBarCodeRead = e => {
    this.setState({ qrcode: e.data });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          barCodeTypes={[RNCamera.props.BarCodeType.qr]}
          flashMode={RNCamera.props.FlashMode.on}
          style={styles.preview}
          onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
          ref={cam => (this.props = cam)}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white"
            }}
          >
            {this.props.qrcode}
          </Text>
        </RNCamera>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
}

export default App;
```

**

Comment: Are you developing for Android or IOS?

Comment: @Reza Sorry, iOS

Comment: Did you add its library manually ?

Comment: @Reza No, I installed by - npm install react-native-camera

Comment: I mean the library of react native-camera

Comment: @Reza Yes, I installed with XCode manually

Comment: So it should be exist in the folder of library in xcode. Also it should be added in setting phase of xcode. Do you confirm that ?

Comment: @Reza ı cannot add setting phases